# Cheating PODs Singletons in C++

Tags: c++, singleton

Suppose we implement a "Meyers" Singleton, with properly deleted copy/assignments operators, private/deleted constructor and private destructor, which returns the instance as

```
static Singleton& instance()
{
     static Singleton s;
     return s;
}
```

Suppose also that the Singleton doesn't have any pointers/dynamic allocation, but only basic PODs, or, in other words, the default copy constructor (if would have been available) would work fine using just bit-wise copy. Then, isn't it possible to simply duplicate it via a `memcpy`, as in

```
Singleton s = Singleton::instance();
Singleton *scopy = (Singleton*)malloc(sizeof(Singleton));
memcpy(scopy, &s, sizeof(Singleton));
```

Can one protect against such an "attack"?

Comment: In C++ ultimately anyone can bypass your safe stuff by casting to a pointer and spewing junk all over it. You just have to assume the user of your code isn't stupid or evil. Unfortunately this assumption doesn't always hold, usually on the former case.

Comment: @NeilKirk unfortunately true :))

Comment: Probably not, at least not practically at all. C++ attempts to protect against accidents, not intentional subversion (aka "protects from Murphy, not Machiavelli").

Comment: @JerryCoffin I like that quote!

Comment: @JerryCoffin good one!